# Dialogflow fulfillment inline editor api request

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'am tryng to get the bot to answer information that received from a API , can't get it working tho.

In firebase console log I can see the api indeed respond with the information that I need .

All the code below:

```js
'use strict';

const axios = require('axios');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }



  function callAPI(agent){

    const food = agent.parameters.Food;
    const subject = agent.parameters.Subject;
    const number = agent.parameters.number;

    const question = subject + " "+number +" "+food;
    const questionReady = question.replace(/ /g, '+');

    const apiKey = "key";
    const baseUrl = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/quickAnswer?q=";

    const apiUrl =  baseUrl + questionReady + "&apiKey=" + apiKey;

    axios.get(apiUrl).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);   
        console.log(result.data);   
        console.log(result.data.answer);

        agent.add(result);
        agent.add(result.data);
        agent.add(result.data.answer);

    });


  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('food', callAPI);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Firebase console log:

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htDz3.jpg)

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? Give us some feedback

Comment: to call external APIs make sure your billing is enabled

Comment: and your function should return promise

Comment: I'am not getting any type of erros , just can't show on the bot answer what the api returned , currently I am using the blaze payment plan , what is missing is the return promise from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you're not using a `Promise` or an `async` function call, so your Handler is returning nothing before your call to the API completes.

To fix this, `callAPI()` needs to return the Promise that `axios.get()` returns. Similarly, your Intent Handler that calls `callAPI()` needs to return that Promise (or another promise from the `then()` block) as well.

The Dialogflow library requires this so it knows to wait for the API call to be completed (and the Promise to thus be resolved) before returning anything to the user.

In your case, this is as simple as changing the call to `axios.get()` to something like

```
return axios.get(apiUrl).then((result) => {
  // Rest of this call here
```

Comment: Answer updated, but see my comment to your "answer" above.